# Replace everything before numbers using str_replace_all

Tags: r

I wan to use `str_replace_all` to replace an substitute everything before a number in a string.

My code below does not work

```
require("stringr")
county <- c("ctr27", "sb03", "nst08", "nst25", "st15",  "st26")
str_replace_all(county, "nst[^0-9.]|st[^0-9.]", "ami")
```

Expected output

```
"ctr27" "sb03" "ami08" "ami25" "ami15"  "ami26"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be achieved using a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
str_replace_all(county, "nst|st(?=\\d+)", "ami")
# [1] "ctr27" "sb03"  "ami08" "ami25" "ami15" "ami26"
```

Answer (score 1):

As the example shows single instance of replacement, we can also use `str_replace`.  In addition, we can capture the digits as a group and replace with the backreference

```
str_replace(county, "nst|st(\\d+)", "ami\\1")
#[1] "ctr27" "sb03"  "ami08" "ami25" "ami15" "ami26"
```